# Is it possible to access anchors in a querystring via PHP?

Tags: php, url, query-string, anchor

I have a page that is accessed via a URL like this:

http://power-coder.net/Test/something.php?id=3#Page1

I know how to access the id parameter using $_GET, however is there a way for me to access the #Page1 part?  I have looked at the $_SERVER array and the REQUEST_URI ends at ?id=3.

I know that I could also change the #Page1 to be an additional parameter like &Page=1, however there is a fair bit of code using the old URL type that I would like to avoid re-writing if at all possible.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there isn't a way. The fragment part (the label after #) is not transmitted to the server.

The browser retrieve the document http://power-coder.net/Test/something.php?id=3 and then go to the correct anchor (if there is one) in the document.

Comment: Thanks, I just discovered this myself a moment ago by watching the request logs while I loaded the page.

Answer (score 3):

The relevant text from [the specs](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2396.html):

> 4.1. Fragment Identifier
>
> When a URI reference is used to perform a retrieval action on the
>   identified resource, the optional fragment identifier, separated from
>   the URI by a crosshatch ("#") character, consists of additional
>   reference information to be interpreted by the user agent after the
>   retrieval action has been successfully completed.  As such, it is not
>   part of a URI, but is often used in conjunction with a URI.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is still searching for a solution.

Just put '&' before the anchor tag:

http://example.com/Test/something.php?id=3&#Page1

Tested on Chrome, Firefox, Safari and IE11