# How can I access the value after a # in a URL?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to obtain anchor part of URL after # in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032242/how-to-obtain-anchor-part-of-url-after-in-php)
>   [Is it possible to access anchors in a querystring via PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484113/is-it-possible-to-access-anchors-in-a-querystring-via-php)

i need to find a way to do this, facebook does it so it has to be possible....

If a user goes to this URL in the browser
http://localhost/index.php?photos=p#**12345**

Then I can have my PHP load a photo with the ID **12345** from mysql

If a user went to
http://localhost/index.php?photos=p#**123456**
Then it would load a photo with id **123456**

I just need help in getting the value in the URL after the **#** and accessing it with PHP if possible?  IF it is not possible, then I maybe I can access it with jQuery and then make an AJAX call to load an image based on this value.

So does anyone know how I can get that value?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484113/is-it-possible-to-access-anchors-in-a-querystring-via-php and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032242/how-to-obtain-anchor-part-of-url-after-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only access this value with Javascript as it is never sent to the server, so PHP never gets it. As Kenny said, you can access it with

```
document.location.hash
```

or

```
window.location.hash
```

but you cannot access it with PHP.

Facebook is a very heavy Javascript site actually. You probably want to do something like send an AJAX request for picture/comment data immediately when the page is loaded. Then when someone presses the 'next' button, you do another request.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the hash in *Javascript* with

```
document.location.hash
```

Comment: I'd like to add that browsers will never send what comes after # in an HTTP request.

Answer (score 1):

The way applications do this is parse the hash using javascript, using `document.location.hash`, and dynamically loading the image using AJAX or another client-side technique. This AJAX call can post the hash to a PHP script that does any necessary server-side processing and returns an image url or something similar.

If you use the `dom:loaded` event many browsers or javascript frameworks support, this happens almost seamlessly.

Answer (score 0):

These values (the anchor) are usually not send to the server by browsers. So you can't depend on them.

Answer (score 0):

It's available in JavaScript as window.location.hash. This is a [dupe of another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940905/can-php-read-the-hash-portion-of-the-url) that has some answers.

Answer (score 0):

The value after the hash identifies a point in the document.  It isn't part of the identity of the document itself.  So a URL like "/path/to/something#section" will cause the browser to request "/path/to/something" from the server, then jump/scroll to the point identified by "section."

You want to build the photo ID into the URL or query string:

http://localhost/index.php?photoId=12345